# url redirection issue

Tags: url, redirect

i want to know if one website totally change except home page url so the website previously page url how to redirect on newly created page please help how to write that particular code

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update your domain, you can do this with `.htaccess`. This is a plain text file you'd put in the public directory.

Put this in it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect all traffic from your old domain to your new one seemlessly.